# Namespace constant in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, constants

Is there any way to define a constant for an entire namespace, rather than just within a class?  For example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{    
    public const string MY_CONST = "Test";

    static class Program
    {
    }
}
```

Gives a compile error as follows:

Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Comment: Note that "constant variable" is an oxymoron. Variables vary, that's why they're called "variables". Constants remain constant, that's why they're called constants. Variables are storage *locations*, constants are *values*. They are completely different; there can be no such thing as a "constant variable".

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I believe it's not possible. But you can create a Class with only constants.

```
public static class GlobalVar
{
    public const string MY_CONST = "Test";
}
```

and then use it like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GlobalVar.MY_CONST);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 as this is the Microsoft recommended method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397677.aspx

Comment: As an aside, another way to implement this is with your web.config or app.config (depending on which one you have). https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256864/105539

Answer (score 14):

This is not possible

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> The **const** keyword is used to modify a declaration of a field or local variable.

Since you can only have a field or local variable within a class, this means you cannot have a global `const`. (i.e namespace const)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the constants in your other classes if you add the "Using Static" too:

```
using static MyNameSpace.MyGlobals;

namespace MyNameSpace {
    public static class MyGlobals{
        public const bool SAVE_LOGSPACE = true;
        public static readonly DateTime BACKTEST_START_DATE = new DateTime(2019,03,01);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, also works with `using static MyNameSpace.MyEnum;`

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. Put it in a static class or enum.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a public static class with constants:

```
namespace Constants
{
    public static class Const
    {
        public const int ConstInt = 420;
    }
}
```

Inside my Program.cs, i would add the following using:

```
using static Constants.Const;
using static System.Console;
```

Now you can freely use the defined constants (which are static by default) and static Console-Methods, e. g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine(ConstInt);
    }
}
```