# .net: Why It's not legal having int inside a namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, types

Why It's not legal having "int" inside a namespace? "int" is a type. right? Just like "class". I know that there are differences between them but there are both Data Types.

```
namespace Ikco.Crp.UI.Common
{
    public int i;
    ....
    ....
}
```

What is the Microsoft' idea about that?

Comment: "Why It's not legal having "int" inside a namespace?" - because that's how the language is defined!

Comment: Is it possible somewhere else, e.g in Java?

Comment: @bigb: java doesn't have global variables, either. OO Languages that do have them include C++ and Python.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818333/namespace-constant-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no global variables in .NET. I guess that's the idea.

Answer (score 12):

There is a difference between defining a class and a variable. When you put a class into a namespace, you define a new type. In your declaration, you are not defining a new type. Instead, you use an existing type (int) to define a variable. The equivalent using classes would be something like

```
namespace Foo{
  class Bar{}   // type definition
  Bar the_bar;  // variable definition
}
```

The second definition isn't allowed, either, so classes and ints really behave the same: there are no global variables in C#.

Answer (score 3):

> "int" is a type. right? Just like "class". I know that there are differences between them but there are both Data Types.

`int` is a data type. `class` is a keyword. The syntax you are using declares a variable inside a namespace, and that is not allowed.