# How to define a compile time constant in an assembly?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, compile-time-constant

First of all: I am using C++-CLI, but I would like to know the solution for C# as well.

Using following code

*assembly "basics"*

```
public ref class CONSTS abstract sealed
{
public:
  static const int  SUCCESS     = 1;
  static const int  InProgress  = 101;
};
```

*assembly "program"*

```
enum class EnumReplyLLI
{
  Nothing = 0,
  SUCCESS = CONSTS::SUCCESS,      // C2057
  Busy    = CONSTS::InProgress,   // C2057
  ...
};
```

I get the error **C2057: expected constant expression**

How can I define a compile-time constant and use it in another assembly?
My code is almost identical to the accepted answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818333/namespace-constant-in-c-sharp), but this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real equivalent of `C#` `const` in `C++/CLI` is [`literal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5yzft952.aspx), so your `CONSTS` class should look like:

```
public ref class CONSTS abstract sealed
{
public:
    literal int  SUCCESS = 1;
    literal int  InProgress = 101;
};
```

Comment: doesn't compile. Error C4693. See http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/603702-abstract-sealed-literal.  As stated by @BenVoigt in this post, it would be a compiler bug... I am using VS 2008 SP1.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Just tried and it compiles with VS2013 without warnings, anyway C4693 is a warning, not an error. Also, the raising of the warning was a bug in previous versions of the compiler. If it doesn't compile can you try with http://www.coderforlife.com/c-cli-static-classes-with-delegates-and-literals/ ?

Comment: VS 2008 shows errors to me, so I can't compile unfortunately. Changing the compiler isn't an option here, so it seems like there is no solution to my issue.

Comment: Can you take off `abstract sealed`?  I know that would make the class non-static but if you don;t have any "real" instance members it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I removed `sealed`, that was sufficient. Not perfect, but working. I won't instantiate it anyway. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's not working in C++, but here's the equivalent code in C#:

```
public static class CONSTS 
{
  public const int  SUCCESS     = 1;
  public const int  InProgress  = 101;
};

enum EnumReplyLLI
{
  Nothing = 0,
  SUCCESS = CONSTS.SUCCESS,     
  Busy    = CONSTS.InProgress,  
};
```

Comment: did you verify it? If yes, you should remove the c2057 comments. Also, shouldn't the class CONSTS be static in c#?

Comment: Yes I verified it.  It _can_ be static, but doesn't _have_ to be.

Comment: okay. That makes me wonder even more why it fails in c++.net... I agree. To make it *equivalent* though, it needs to be static. ;-)

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Fair enough - changed it.